# How to solve unknown Server tag "rsweb:ReportViewer"

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have created ssrs report. Now i want to call that report in my aspx page.
I have used following code for this purpose.

```
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" CssClass="rpviewerparm" BackColor="#60759B">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

but i get the below error:
unknown server tag 'rsweb:Reportviewer'.

Comment: Do you have a report server where you deploy said reports to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to register Assembly for working with report viewer control

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

Add it just below page directive.

Answer (score 3):

At the top of your ASPX page yo have to add the reference to the assembly (Register it):

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
```

Also if you plan to add server side code you have to add `using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;`

Note: If you cant find any of these references you should go to your solution exlorer -> right click on references -> Add reference and look for `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` and add it (MS Visual Studio).